# Updating a TextView value every 3 seconds

Tags: java, android, textview

I am a PHP developer, who is new to Android development and Java so please bear with me.

I am developing an extremely simple app for testing and learning purposes.

when the user clicks my app icon, they are presented with a loading screen. I have a TextView with a progress bar underneath.

TextView XML code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/loadingMessage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="@string/loading1" />
```

The value is set to the string loading1 in strings.xml

```
<string name="loading1">Loading Message 1</string>
```

In my loadingscreen.java i have:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LoadingScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);

        TextView loadingMessage1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_loading_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Notice I have the code:

TextView loadingMessage1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage1);

Which I think references the text view.

What I want to happen is that every 3 seconds a different message appears.

So loading message 1... (3 secs) loading message 2... (3 secs) loading message 3..

after loading message 3 i would like a button to replace the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Handler` class:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // change your text here
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3*1000L);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a timer, which executes every 1 second period.. Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) brilliant android dev blog article on periodic execution using timer and Handler.